# WSO2 APIM 2.2.0 How to remove tabs from API store - API View

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Is there a way to disable tabs in WSO2 API Manager Store 2.2.0 API Console tabs ?
For example, i don't want SDK and Forum tabs to visible in APIM Store API Store console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sub theme and hide these sections. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme